# I can't build an apk because it says expo build is deprecated, and using eas build it gives me an error

Tags: android, reactjs, git, react-native, expo

i have been trying to build the apk of my react native app, i started this one using expo, but every time i try to run the command expo build:android it gives me the following

error:

PS C:\xooc-app> expo build:android expo build:android has been replaced by eas build. Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/turtle-goes-out-to-sea-d334db2a6b60

Run the following: › npm install -g eas-cli › eas build -p android https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/ expo build:android will be discontinued on Jan 4, 2023 (232 days left). Unsupported SDK version: Our app builders do not yet support SDK version 45. The latest version of the SDK is 45.0.0. Unsupported SDK Version Error: Unsupported SDK Version in Object.checkIfSdkIsSupported (C:\Users\elektra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\utils.ts:80:11) in AndroidBuilder.checkProjectConfig (C:\Users\elektra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\AndroidBuilder.ts:50:5) in AndroidBuilder.prepareProjectInfo (C:\Users\elektra\ AppData\Roaming\ npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\BaseBuilder.ts:72:5) in AndroidBuilder.command (C:\Users\elektra\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\ src\commands\ compile\BaseBuilder.ts:41:7)

Now, as I understand now, eas build must be used, and I have already installed everything in the project, the problem is that, for example, when executing the eas build command, it gives me the following error

PS C:\xooc-app> eas build --local √ Select Platform » Android git command not found. Please install it before continuing or set EAS_NO_VCS=1 to use EAS CLI without Git (or any other version control system). Learn more: https://expo.fyi/eas-vcs-workflow

And in all the commands that I try to execute easily it gives me this error:

git command not found. Please install it before continuing or set EAS_NO_VCS=1 to use EAS CLI without Git (or any other version control system).

that happens with any eas command, it is assumed that I already installed everything in the project as indicated in the documentation, but it only gives that error, and even after installing eas-cli, it never added any file like eas.json, or . give

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "xooc-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "build": "expo build:android",
    "bundle-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --sourcemap-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.map --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "~0.16.21",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.9.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "eas": "^0.1.0",
    "eas-cli": "^0.52.0",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.9",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-md5": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "rn-emoji-keyboard": "^0.7.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is my .gitignore

```
node_modules/
.expo/
dist/
npm-debug.*
*.jks
*.p8
*.p12
*.key
*.mobileprovision
*.orig.*
web-build/

# macOS
.DS_Store
```

and my app.json

```
{ 
  "expo": {
    "name": "xooc-app",
    "slug": "xooc-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "packagerOpts":{
      "sourceExts": ["cjs"]
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.xooc.xoocapp",
      "versionCode":1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed Git? If so, you'll need to make sure the other software can *find* the installed Git (via PATH for instance); if not, you'll need to install Git (it's a separate package).

Comment: Hello. I'm having equally the same error. My eas.json wasn't also added. Please did you later solve this??